# Missing factor levels in glm with multiple variables

Tags: r, regression

I know similar questions have been asked, but I can't quite seem to understand it.

I have a model `glm(freq~DayOfWeek+PdDistrict, family ='poisson',data=df)` to look at what days of week and what police districts have more crime. When I get the summary out, the first level of the factors from each are missing. For example, Day OfWeek sunday is missing and PdDistrict #1 is missing too.

I understand that the intercept is the reference and this would make sense to me if  I only had one variable. But I have 2 here. How can I interpret the intercept if one factor level from both variables is being used as the reference?

Comment: You can because without fitting their interaction you're assuming the differences observed between DayOfWeek are the same regardless what level of PdDistrict it is. In other words, difference between Tuesday and Monday is going to be the same in all PdDistrict; there is no need to "combine" the interpretation between the two independent variables.

Comment: Ah, okay. i get it now. What if I changed it to `freq~DayOfWeek*PdDistrict`